# OrientDB - Return JSON from a Select query

Tags: orientdb

With orientDB you can insert / update directly using JSON as the input using the 'CONTENT' keyword which is great.  ODB takes care of the mappings.

Id like to be able to return JSON as well from SELECT queries - is this possible?

Kurt

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.toJSON()` method.

Syntax: `<value>.toJSON([<format>])`

Example:

```
create class Test extends V
insert into Test content {"attr1": "value 1", "attr2": "value 2"}

select @this.toJson('rid,version,fetchPlan:in_*:-2 out_*:-2') from Test
```

Ref.: [SQL Methods - .toJSON()](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Methods.html#tojson)

Comment: Sorry just saw the Ref link below your Answer!

Comment: Sorry just saw the Ref link below your Answer!  This worked (not sure what the fetchPlan part does will look into this) - is there a way to also return any edges out of the vertext as well as sub JSON doc with attributes?  Either as rid refs or even 'unpacked' so has embedded JSON is the E with all its attributes?  Thanks heaps really appreciated it